# Google Chrome requests elevation on startup

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Does anyone have any idea why chrome would be requesting elevation every time I start it?

I am running Windows 7 32bit and have no chrome extensions, reinstalling does not help.

The dialog box that appears on the customary darkened background is:-

```
User Account Control

Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer?

Program Name: Google Chrome
Verified Publisher: Google Inc
File Origin: Hard drive on this computer

Yes No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, the answer was the software was set to run as administrator.

To resolve I closed chrome, then I found the shortcut (lnk file) in the start menu by typing chrome into the windows search box, then I right clicked the chrome icon and selected properties from the drop down list.  In the dialog that appeared I selected the compatibility tab, then clicked the "change settings for all users" button and then unticked the run as administrator check box.

(This fixed the issue even though I do not directly use the shortcut to launch chrome, I have the icon on my taskbar).

Comment: "Run as administrator" property applies to the *target* of the shortcut, not the shortcut itself.